# What is an excellent instant-run Python debugger/shell?

Tags: python, ide, editor

So I am really annoyed by using IDLE. I need an IDE or simply a shell that can take a .py file and run it immediately, showing me the results.

I've configured Notepad++ to run python console, and I have to add "raw_input()" at the end of every file so it doesn't disappear. Problem is, if there is a syntax error, it won't show me the error, it won't go to raw_input. So I am forced to use IDLE.

I tried running DreamPie shell with notepad++ but it doesn't work that way.  Neither does the IDLE shell.

How can I write Python code and then instantly see the results without using IDLE's editor?

EDIT: I found a plugin called PyNPP it allows you to run the 'interactive shell' for Python immediately, using a shortcut like F6 in Notepad++. This seems to work great! Sublime 2 seems like a nice editor too, but I couldn't get it to run shell.

Comment: You might want to check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/81584/what-ide-to-use-for-python

Comment: Pretty much every powerful (customizable) editor can be taught this trick. Alternatively, use an OS with a shell that's fun to use and keep a shell open to run the file, then it can be a matter of `Ctrl+S Alt+Tab Arrow Up Return`.

Comment: Marking as a duplicate of http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/81584/what-ide-to-use-for-python (also linked by TorelTwiddler).

Comment: Except it's not, the main argument of the question is about notepad++ not other IDEs. Also most IDEs do not allow for Python to be run-and-debugged on the fly.

Comment: The Zeus editor can run a Python script and capture the output produced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[IPython](http://ipython.scipy.org/moin/) is a souped up version of the standard python shell. It does auto completion and syntax highlighting along with automatically providing help docs for various functions.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend pydev for eclipse. You can download it from [the pydev website](http://pydev.org/)

Comment: I kind of hate eclipse, but I might give it a try in sometime.

Answer (score 3):

What kinds of scripts are you running? If you are doing just pure text output scripts without needing a GUI event loop, check out Sublime. It's a gorgeous editor, and extensible in python if you want to make addins for it. iPython is a great shell which has autocomplete (sort of).

http://www.sublimetext.com/

Komodo Edit is pretty good, has decent autocomplete and its free, it also doesn't suffer from the GUI event loop limitation that Sublime has (though it is also a larger application, and not nearly as pretty).

http://www.activestate.com/komodo-edit

Eclipse, as mentioned earlier, is a great IDE though it is huge - I personally prefer sublime as my goto editor.

Comment: Komodo has problems, it freezes unexpectedly and it does not have any built-in python support. I tried sublime, looks and works great, but I can't run Python debugging with it. I can't even run the code through sublime.

Comment: Sublime is more of a text editor than an IDE - you're right, it doesn't allow debugging, though it has a default build system for Python. If you have a Python file loaded in the editor, just press F7 and it should execute. Komodo also has Python support, after you configure it. For a full-featured IDE with traditional debug support, check out Eclipse with PyDev. It's a behemoth application, but it works. You can download ready-to-go installs here at www.aptana.com or at www.easyeclipse.org

Comment: I see. I couldn't get it to run the python file. Eclipse PyDev is something I must try soon, it's just that I am not a big fan of eclipse.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend [Emacs](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/) with [python-mode.el](https://launchpad.net/python-mode).

This will be harder to get into initially, since Emacs has a bit of a learning curve. However, once you have it down, it has all the advantages of an interactive shell and an IDE. When you're working normally, it's like any other text editor/IDE, where you have syntax highlighting, code completion, and other nice features. When you want to be in a shell, control-c ! will pop one open, and you can paste code in, or highlight your code and send it to the shell.

That being said, Emacs isn't for everyone. Still, a lot of people like it once they learn it. Definitely worth giving a try.

Comment: I thought about adding a comment "Or you might consider Emacs' distant cousin vim" but decided that might garnish criticism. Also, my only experience with vim is nethack =P.

Comment: Sorry no, I am usually working in windows, and I'd rather just click to the code I want to go. Nothing is faster than a click. I'm sure after learning vim / emacs and doing it for a while, it might be just as fine, but it's simply not for me.

Comment: To each their own. Still, while a click may be fast if you already have your hand on the mouse, I rarely have my hand on the mouse while I'm writing code (Although I do use the mouse when I'm reading code, even in Emacs). So, while the individual "navigate" action may be faster with a mouse, an "edit->navigate->edit" cycle is often faster with the keyboard. Just something to consider.

Comment: AH I see what you mean, that is a good argument for using it. It's just something I haven't learned yet, but I'm sure once I do I won't go back.

Answer (score 0):

I tried several Sublimetext3, Vim etc. but there was always one or more issues.
Then I came across Zeus
http://www.zeusedit.com/index.html

Briljant simple and running straight out of the box if you set the link to the compiler. I am now on the 45 days trial period but I am going to buy it.